# How to zip files in XP's command line without additional tools/downloads

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, zip

After prowling google, and checking an old thread in ServerFault, I thought I would try here. Without any additional downloads, on a fresh install of XP SP3, how can I run a script to extract AND zip a file into a .zip?

People have tried saying to use third party utilities, but that requires downloading a program as well, and making sure they're in the same location all the time. I don't want to download the Microsoft Resource Kit just for this one chunk of functionality on multiple computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with VBScript. [This question has been asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted), and this answer comes from [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20840/jay):

```
Dim fso, winShell, MyTarget, MySource, file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set winShell = createObject("shell.application")


MyTarget = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
MySource = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)

Wscript.Echo "Adding " & MySource & " to " & MyTarget

'create a new clean zip archive
Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(MyTarget, True)
file.write("PK" & chr(5) & chr(6) & string(18,chr(0)))
file.close

winShell.NameSpace(MyTarget).CopyHere winShell.NameSpace(MySource).Items

do until winShell.namespace(MyTarget).items.count = winShell.namespace(MySource).items.count
    wscript.sleep 1000 
loop

Set winShell = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a single, simple cmd.exe command for this.  (Through PowerShell v5.0+)

To zip:

```
powershell Compress-Archive -LiteralPath 'C:\mypath\testfile.txt' -DestinationPath "C:\mypath\Test.zip"
```

To unzip:

```
powershell Expand-Archive -LiteralPath "C:\mypath\Test.Zip" -DestinationPath "C:\mypath" -Force
```

Sources:

- [Compress-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6)
- [Expand-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6)

Special thanks to @Ramhound

Answer (score -1):

I believe that Windows XP does have a built in function for this called Compact.

[COMPACT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490884.aspx)

Comment: That does not create a .zip file; that just added the Compress attribute to the file/directory

Comment: My mistake, i thought that worked.

Answer (score -1):

To do this on Windows XP without installation of VB runtime and other components, I would use 7zip's command line tools 7za.exe and copy the required files to windows/system32 to save having to PATH to the 7zip installation directory. 7za can zip up as a zip file instead of a .7z file to aid compatibility. Futher information here https://www.7-zip.org/faq.html